# How to input a graph into an algorithm with vertices, adj. nodes and edges cost?

Tags: python, input, graph, dijkstra

I am implementing a version of Dijkstra's algorithm on python, but I don't know how to build a graph for the input.

My current version uses a constructor, but it gives me troubles when I need to iterate through the distance's list, because I bounded it to the node's key.
n stands for neighbors.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, key, n, cost):
        self.key = key
        self.n = n
        self.cost = cost


    def c(u, v):
        return u.cost[v-1]


    def dijkstra(g, u):
        # nodes with lower cost
        N = [u]
        ln = len(g)

        D = [float('Inf')] * (ln)
        p = [None] * (ln)

        for v in g:
            if v in u.n:
                D[v.key-1] = Graph.c(u, v.key)
                p[v.key-1] = u.key

        while len(N) != len(V):
            # Finds minimum D[w]
            w = 0
            for i in range (1, ln):
                if D[i] < D[w] and g[i] not in N:
                    w = i

            N.append(g[w])

            # Neighbors of w
            for v in g[w].n:
                if v not in N:
                    if D[w] + Graph.c(g[w],v.key) < D[v.key-1]:
                        D[v.key-1] = D[w] + Graph.c(g[w], v.key)
                        p[v.key-1] = g[w].key

        D[0] = 0
        print(D)
        print(p)


# Builds the graph
A = Graph(1, None, None)
B = Graph(2, None, None)
C = Graph(3, None, None)
D = Graph(4, None, None)
E = Graph(5, None, None)

A.n = [B, C]
B.n = [C, D, E]
C.n = [B, D, E]
D.n = []
E.n = [D]

A.cost = [None, 4, 2, None, None]
B.cost = [None, None, 3, 2, 3]
C.cost = [None, 1, None, 4, 5]
D.cost = [None, None, None, None, None]
E.cost = [None, None, None, 1, None]

V = [A, B, C, D, E]

Graph.dijkstra(V, A)
```

The input needs to include the vertices, the adj nodes, and the cost of each edge.

Comment: Please add programming-language tag

Comment: What do you mean?